# VBA specific region copying and pasting

Tags: excel, vba

Does the `CurrentRegion` function in VBA copy everything from the left to the right when selected? If so, how can you make it copy only values to the right of your starting range?

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("F1").CurrentRegion.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```

I tried with the above code but it copied everything including the redundant data.

Comment: Something like `Dim lCol As Long : lCol = Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` with `ActiveSheet.Range("F1",Cells(1,lCol))`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this.

**WAY 1**

My Assumptions:

1. The range to be copied has 1 row.
2. There is nothing on the left hand
   side of the range for which you want to find the current region.

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub SampleA()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1 'Activesheet ' Change as applicbale
        
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("F1")
        
    Dim CurRegion As Range
    Set CurRegion = rng.CurrentRegion
        
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
        
    For Each aCell In CurRegion
        If Intersect(rng, aCell) Is Nothing Then
            If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToCopy = aCell
            Else
                Set rngToCopy = Application.Union(rngToCopy, aCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next aCell
        
    Debug.Print rngToCopy.Address
    'rngToCopy.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

**WAY 2**

This finds the last column and constructs the range

```
Sub SampleB()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1 'Activesheet ' Change as applicbale
        
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("F1")
        
    Dim CurRegion As Range
    Set CurRegion = rng.CurrentRegion
    
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    With ws
        Set rngToCopy = .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1), .Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + CurRegion.Columns.Count - 1))
    End With
    
    Debug.Print rngToCopy.Address
    'rngToCopy.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

**Way 3**

As suggested by @Notus_Panda. This finds the last column and constructs the range

```
Sub SampleC()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1 'Activesheet ' Change as applicbale
    
    With ws
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("F1")
        
        Dim lCol As Long
        lCol = .Cells(rng.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Dim rngToCopy As Range

        Set rngToCopy = .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1), .Cells(rng.Row, lCol))
    End With
    
    Debug.Print rngToCopy.Address
    'rngToCopy.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

PS: I have not done any error handling. I am sure you can manage that